# Sideway toggle - slide right to open and slide left to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to a sideway toggle- when user clicks it will smoothly slide to right and when user wants to close it, it will slide in to the left

I've created my JSFiddle, but I'm not sure how can I integrate the slide in slide out when user clicks.
Here's the live : https://jsfiddle.net/gmf1sypw/

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Happening</h3>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aliquam deserunt harum rem earum assumenda perspiciatis expedita. Aliquid distinctio tenetur fugiat qui recusandae obcaecati voluptates.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }


    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 250px;
      position: relative;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-left: 40px solid orange;
      padding: 15px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      font-size: small;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .wrapper h3 {
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin-left: -30px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [jQuery UI slide effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Effects/Slide&redirect=no), specifying your direction. Alternately you can use some jQuery to shift the element:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', function() {
  var pntLeft = $('.wrapper').parent().offset().left, 
      chdLeft = $('.wrapper').position().left,
      toggleLeft = (Math.floor(chdLeft - pntLeft)) == -450 ? "0px" : "-450px";
  $('.wrapper').animate({ left: toggleLeft }, 400);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-left: 40px solid orange;
  padding: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: small;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
}
.wrapper h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Happening</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aliquam deserunt harum rem earum assumenda perspiciatis expedita. Aliquid distinctio tenetur fugiat qui recusandae obcaecati voluptates.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Edit: This option lets you apply the animation to the content only: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmf1sypw/4/).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Instead of hiding the whole thing, I just want the content to be toggled and the header happening stays in place.

Comment: Thanks! One question: how do I make sure the whole box with orange border slides with the content? so it looks like it is sliding out and in?

Comment: Just add your border styles to the .content div, remove them from the .wrapper and you should be all set. Of course you'll need to tweak the dimensions of the .content div as well to line up.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? A quick example of changing the border styles for the desired effect: https://jsfiddle.net/gmf1sypw/5/